# Mongodb aggregation by day based on unix timestamp

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have googled alot, but not found any helpful solution... I want to find total number of daily users. 
I have a collection named **session_log** having documents like following

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52c690955d3cdd831504ce30"),
    "SORTID" : NumberLong(1388744853),
    "PLAYERID" : 3,
    "LASTLOGIN" : NumberLong(1388744461),
    "ISLOGIN" : 1,
    "LOGOUT" : NumberLong(1388744853)
}
```

I want to aggregate from LASTLOGIN...

This is my query:

```
db.session_log.aggregate(
    { $group : {
        _id: {
            LASTLOGIN : "$LASTLOGIN"
        },
        count: { $sum: 1 }
    }}
);
```

But it is aggregating by each login time, not by each day. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: which mongo version you used?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### MongoDB 4.0 and newer

Use **[`$toDate`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/)**

```
db.session_log.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "$dateToString": {
                "format": "%Y-%m-%d",
                "date": {
                    "$toDate": { 
                        "$multiply": [1000, "$LASTLOGIN"]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    } }
])
```

or **[`$convert`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/convert/)**

```
db.session_log.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "$dateToString": {
                "format": "%Y-%m-%d",
                "date": {
                    "$convert": { 
                        "input":  { 
                            "$multiply": [1000, "$LASTLOGIN"] 
                        }, 
                        "to": "date"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    } }
])
```

---

### MongoDB >= 3.0 and < 4.0:

```
db.session_log.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "$dateToString": {
                "format": "%Y-%m-%d",
                "date": {
                    "$add": [
                        new Date(0), 
                        { "$multiply": [1000, "$LASTLOGIN"] }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    } }
])
```

---

You would need to convert the `LASTLOGIN` field to a millisecond timestamp through multiplying the value by 1000

```
{ "$multiply": [1000, "$LASTLOGIN"] }
```

, then convert to a date

```
"$add": [
    new Date(0),
    { "$multiply": [1000, "$LASTLOGIN"] }
]
```

and this can be done in the **[`$project`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** pipeline by adding your milliseconds time to a zero-milliseconds `Date(0)` object, then extract **[`$year`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/year/#exp._S_year)**, **[`$month`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/month/#exp._S_month)**, **[`$dayOfMonth`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dayOfMonth/#exp._S_dayOfMonth)** parts from the converted date which you can then use in your **[`$group`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline to group the documents by the day.

You should thus change your aggregation pipeline to this:

```
var project = {
    "$project":{ 
        "_id": 0,
        "y": {
            "$year": {
                "$add": [
                    new Date(0),
                    { "$multiply": [1000, "$LASTLOGIN"] }
                ]
            }
        },
        "m": {
            "$month": {
                "$add": [
                    new Date(0),
                    { "$multiply": [1000, "$LASTLOGIN"] }
                ]
            }
        }, 
        "d": {
            "$dayOfMonth": {
                "$add": [
                    new Date(0),
                    { "$multiply": [1000, "$LASTLOGIN"] }
                ]
            }
        }
    } 
},
group = {   
    "$group": { 
        "_id": { 
            "year": "$y", 
            "month": "$m", 
            "day": "$d"
        },  
        "count" : { "$sum" : 1 }
    }
};
```

Running the aggregation pipeline:

```
db.session_log.aggregate([ project, group ])
```

would give the following results (based on the sample document):

```
{ "_id" : { "year" : 2014, "month" : 1, "day" : 3 }, "count" : 1 }
```

---

An improvement would be to run the above in a single pipeline as

```
var group = {   
    "$group": { 
        "_id": {    
            "year": {
                "$year": {
                    "$add": [
                        new Date(0),
                        { "$multiply": [1000, "$LASTLOGIN"] }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "mmonth": {
                "$month": {
                    "$add": [
                        new Date(0),
                        { "$multiply": [1000, "$LASTLOGIN"] }
                    ]
                }
            }, 
            "day": {
                "$dayOfMonth": {
                    "$add": [
                        new Date(0),
                        { "$multiply": [1000, "$LASTLOGIN"] }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },  
        "count" : { "$sum" : 1 }
    }
};
```

Running the aggregation pipeline:

```
db.session_log.aggregate([ group ])
```

---

Comment: Could you please explain why do we need all this math gymnastics to do a simple type conversion, to make mongo work with Dates, and why my solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43451053/cannot-use-dayofmonth-aggregate-with-expression doesn't work?

Comment: using this wave getting error like " gmtime failed to convert time_t"

Comment: @ChristianDecheryMongoDB does not allow interpolation of a pipeline variable/operator from a function since everything is parsed to BSON on input i.e. within the pipeline MongoDB processes BSON operators to native C++ code, thus JavaScript or anything else is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

First thing is your date is stored in `timestamp` so you need to first convert `timestamp` to `ISODate` using adding `new Date(0)` and multiply `timestamp` to `1000` then you will get the  `ISODate` like this :

`{"$add":[new Date(0),{"$multiply":[1000,"$LASTLOGIN"]}]}` this convert to timestamp to ISODate.

Now using [date aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/) you need to convert `ISODate` in required format using [$concat](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/) and then group by final formatting date so aggregation query will be :

```
db.session_log.aggregate({
  $project: {
    date: {
      $concat: [{
        $substr: [{
          $year: {
            "$add": [new Date(0), {
              "$multiply": [1000, "$LASTLOGIN"]
            }]
          }
        }, 0, 4]
      }, "/", {
        $substr: [{
          $month: {
            "$add": [new Date(0), {
              "$multiply": [1000, "$LASTLOGIN"]
            }]
          }
        }, 0, 4]
      }, "/", {
        $substr: [{
          $dayOfMonth: {
            "$add": [new Date(0), {
              "$multiply": [1000, "$LASTLOGIN"]
            }]
          }
        }, 0, 4]
      }]
    }
  }
}, {
  "$group": {
    "_id": "$date",
    "count": {
      "$sum": 1
    }
  }
})
```

If you will used mongo version `3.0` and above then use [dateToString](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/) operator to convert `ISODate` to predefined format, and aggregation query is :

```
db.session_log.aggregate({
  "$project": {
    "ISODate": {
      "$add": [new Date(0), {
        "$multiply": [1000, "$LASTLOGIN"]
      }]
    }
  }
}, {
  "$project": {
    "yearMonthDay": {
      "$dateToString": {
        "format": "%Y-%m-%d",
        "date": "$ISODate"
      }
    }
  }
}, {
  "$group": {
    "_id": "$yearMonthDay",
    "count": {
      "$sum": 1
    }
  }
})
```