# Cannot use $dayOfMonth aggregate with expression

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

So, I need to extract the day-of-week for some objects to make some aggregations. But all my documents have is a timestamp, not a Date. So I'm trying to use $dayOfMonth (and others) with an expression, I can't figure out what it is not working.

Here is my query (along with a helper function to create my date from the timestamp):

```
db.Logging.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            "timestamp": { $gte: dateToTimestamp("2017-04-10") }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: { 
            _id: 0,
            timestamp: "$timestamp",
            dia: { $dayOfMonth: myDate("$timestamp") }
        }
    }
])

function dateToTimestamp(str) {
    let d = new Date( str );
    return d.getTime() + d.getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000;
}

function myDate( ts) {
    var d = new ISODate();
    d.setTime( ts );
    return d;
}
```

The problem seems to be in passing the value of `$timestamp` to the `myDate` function. If I use a literal (e.g. 1492430243) either as the value of `ts` inside the function or as the value of the parameter passed to `myDate` it works fine.

In other words: this `$dayOfMonth: myDate("1492430243")` works.

Although a solution has been shown to work here ([Mongodb aggregation by day based on unix timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33078773/mongodb-aggregation-by-day-based-on-unix-timestamp) - a pretty ugly solution, if I may add), I want to know why my solution doesn't. As per mongodb docs, `$dayOfMonth` works with Date types, my function returns a date, so what is wrong?

Comment: It looks like aggregation framework does not evaluate JavaScript. Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31620582/custom-functions-calculated-columns-mongodb-projection

Comment: It seems a rather erratic behaviour from the aggregation framework, because in the $match it works with no problem, but not for $project. I wonder if this also happens in other sections as well.

Comment: Voted to reopen.